# nginx: selectively stripping URL params

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Some of the customers of the e-commerce website that I manage are behind a ZScaler firewall, and it appends garbage query params to all outgoing requests; so when my website makes a HTTP GET request like:

```
/api/cartinventoryitems?cartsummaryid=eq.1234
```

It comes through to nginx as:

```
/api/cartinventoryitems?cartsummaryid=eq.1234&_sm_byp=iVVJvVj6nqJDqQj5
```

The endpoint behind my `/api/` location does not like this, so I am trying to strip it out.

Right now, I am trying to use `rewrite` at the head of my `server` block, like so:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        rewrite ^(.*)([&?]_sm_byp=\w+) $1 last;
        ...
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rewrite` (as well as `location`) nginx directives works with so-called **normalized** URI which is not included the query part of request (other normalization steps includes decoding the text encoded in the URL-encoded “%XX” form, resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, and possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single slash). You should change [`$args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) nginx variable instead. Using your regex it would look like

```
if ($args ~ ^(.*)(&?_sm_byp=\w+)) {
    set $args $1;
}
```

Change from `[&?]` to `&?` isn't a mistake. It is made because `$args` variable does not include the question sign, so `&` character can be present if `_sm_byp` query argument isn't the only one or can be absent otherwise.

I can suggest more advanced regex (authored by myself) which allows to cut some query argument from the query string no matter it is at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of that string:

```
if ($args ~ (.*)(^|&)_sm_byp=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
    set $args $1$3$4;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much - both versions work, but I like yours better. Followup question: how could I have figured this out on my own? I've tried reading the NGINX docs - I did that for a few hours before I asked this - but I think there were too many conceptual hurdles for me to overcome, in order to understand the issue as you explained it.